# Unique search results in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, search

I am using [Ernie Miller's Metasearch](http://metautonomo.us/projects/metasearch/) in a rails 3 app and have run into a problem.

In my Model

```
class Prospect < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :steps
```

In my controller

```
@search=Prospect.search(params[:search])
```

In my view (search form)

```
 <%= f.date_select :steps_updated_at_greater_than%>
```

This works such that I get all the Prospects where steps have been updated since date_select.  My problem is that if there has been multiple updated steps, I get duplicates in @search, which I do not want when I go to format my search results in a view.

My question is what is the best way to remove the duplicates from @search? Or prevent duplicates from being added to @search in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want:

```
@search = Prospect.search(params[:search])

@search.relation.select("DISTINCT(step_id), prospects.*")
```

Comment: This worked for me..and more importantly I now understand how it worked.Thank a lot for the help guys, it was driving me nuts.

Answer (score 2):

```
@search=Prospect.search(params[:search]).select('DISTINCT step_id')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@search = Prospect.search(params[:search])
@prospects = @search.relation.uniq
```